# AzureML SDK v2 list compute error AttributeError: 'Databricks' object has no attribute 'tags'

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I am using AzureML SDK v2. I run the following code

```
ml_ws_client = MLClient(credential=credential,subscription_id=subscription_id, resource_group_name=resource_group,  workspace_name=ws_name)

for comp in ml_ws_client.compute.list(compute_type="amlcompute"):
    print(comp)
```

which generates the error

`AttributeError: 'Databricks' object has no attribute 'tags'`

How can I get the list of available AMLComputes? In SDK v1 it was easy.

I read
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-ai-ml/azure.ai.ml.operations.computeoperations?view=azure-python#azure-ai-ml-operations-computeoperations-list
and some other tutorials which didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

To list available AMLCompute instances using AzureML SDK v2 you don't need to pass `compute_type` as the list function by default gives amlcompute.
You can use below code snippet to get the list of computes:

```py
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
ml_ws_client = MLClient(credential=credential,subscription_id='', resource_group_name='',  workspace_name='')

for compute in ml_ws_client.compute.list():
    print(compute.name)
```

With the above conde snippet, I was able to get all the available computes.
[image]